# Difference between equivalent output current & secondary RMS output current for flyback

Tags: power, current, flyback

What is difference between equivalent output current & secondary RMS output current for flyback?

Assume Vout = 24V, Output power = 50W

1. If we divide 50W/24V = 2.08A, this is called as equivalent output current (refer image 1)
2. If we calculate the secondary RMS, the value will be almost 3.97A, this is called as secondary RMS output current (refer image 2)

Refer below for calculation details.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

As you can see, if using 1st equation, we can get output power 50W, while if using 2nd equation, we can get output power 96W.

If my amplifier need 4.0A, this 4.0A should be calculated based on equation 1 or equation 2?

If both is correct, does it mean that this 2.1A (50W) can rise maximum to 4A (96W)?

What is the maximum output current can be draw from the output with the same primary peak current?

Comment: Because of my question is related with this question, I have written here. I try to design a flyback converter which has two outputs. First output is main output **24V/1,5A** and second output is for Vcc **18V/0,02A**. When I tyr to calculate secondary peak and rms value, I'm getting some **results that I don't understand**. - Turn ratio for main output (Is1) (24V/1,5A) = 2:1
- turn ratio for Vcc output (Is2) (18V/0,02A) = 2,7:1 *(Input voltage is changeable and not important)* Ip(peak) = 1,52A So, Is1(peak) = 1,52 x 2 = 3,04A ( output current is 1,5 ) Is2(peak) = 1,52 x 2,7 = 4,06A ( output c

Comment: @Bumyamin  Please ask this as a new question. This site requires one question per Question & Answer session. Use the [ASK QUESTION](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top right of each page. You can copy your text from this non-answer into the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, if using 1st equation, we can get output power 50W,
>   while if using 2nd equation, we can get output power 96W.

No, you can't use the 2nd equation meaningfully to obtain output power.

The secondary RMS value of 3.97 amps is the current flowing through the secondary winding and, it may have an average (DC) value that is somewhat related to your DC output current of 2.08 amps but, as an RMS value, it is meaningless to what DC current the final output stage can deliver.

That secondary winding current is a partial triangle/saw-tooth wave raised to a DC value. The clue to it being a partial triangle/saw wave (a basic standard for flyback converters) is the division by 3 in the formula and the square root in front of that part of the formula.

Here's a pictorial example of the input and output winding current waveforms for a 2:1 step down flyback circuit operating in DCM. I think your circuit is probably more like 10:1 and CCM but, the general shape of the waveforms are the same: -

[image]

Comment: Hi @Andy aka, thank you so much for your answer. Based on that, meaning that the total maximum current can be draw from the output to the load is only 2.1A (50W)? If more than that, output voltage will drop. Correct?

Comment: If the flyback converter is designed to work across a range of input supply voltage levels, then operating towards the middle of that range (or above middle) will mean you can probably get a little more output current without excessive voltage variations on the output. However, the devil is in the detail and it's quite usual that the flyback transformer core will saturate slightly above the maximum running point and then you will have disappointment.

Comment: this may be out from the question, just want to ask if how about we measure the output current using DC RMS meter, will it capture the RMS current or the nominal current?

Comment: The DC current measured (ignoring the small amount of ripple) is the RMS value. If the ripple was 100 mA RMS superimposed on 1 amp DC, the total RMS would be 1.005 amps RMS hence the DC value largely is the RMS value.

Comment: Then, meaning that the DC current measured is equal to RMS current (4.0A) ? Not the nominal current (2.1A)?

Comment: In your previous comment you asked me how *we measure the output current using DC RMS meter* and I told you in my previous comment. The RMS current you know refer to IS NOT the DC output current so therefore you can't say *meaning that the DC current measured is equal to RMS current (4.0A)*. If you mean something else then you need to be clear and accurate.

Comment: sorry for confusing. Today I measured my amplifier input current at 24V supply with specific output power, the total current is 4.0A. This 4.0A was measured using DC RMS voltmeter. Therefore I considered it as a DC RMS value. By using this DC RMS value, i want to estimate what is power rating for my power supply (if I want to design them)  wheather it should be  96W (24V x 4A) or 50W (24V x 2.1A).

Comment: Your flyback power supply output power is 50 watts (24 volts x 2.083 amps is 49.992 watts). The 3.92 amps is not your output current but the RMS current of the internal flyback transformer. You cannot use this current to recalculate your output power. The output power is 50 watts and not 96 watts.

Comment: thank you very much! Now I'm clear about that.